# How can I generate code coverage for .Net Core 2.x from integration tests on linux/mac?

Tags: c#, .net-core, integration-testing, code-coverage

I am doing .NET core 2 work on a mac (and my build server is linux) and I'm looking for a way to generate code coverage for *integration* tests that use and embedded web server as the system under test.  I can get coverage for my unit tests but *not* for my Integration style tests.

Im relatively new to .NET but I've familiarized myself with the testing ecosystem as best I can in the last few months.

Currently I'm testing a .NET core 2.2 API using xUnit as my test framework and using the Microsoft supplied `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing` package to generate the test server inside of my tests. Very similar to [this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Then I have tests that use the TestClient to make HTTP requests to the embedded SUT and assert on the response.

I can generate code coverage for my Unit tests using [AltCover](https://github.com/SteveGilham/altcover) and this works great! But when i run altcover over my integration test project, I get no coverage results.

I Have DebugType set to Full on the projects, and debug symbol files appear to be generated for all of the relevant code.

The xUnit test fixture for my SUT

```
namespace Redbox.Product.Tests.Integration.Util
{
    public class TestConfigurationFixture
    {
        private readonly WebApplicationFactory<TestStartup> _webApplicationFactory;

        public TestConfigurationFixture()
        {
            _webApplicationFactory = new CustomWebApplicationFactory<TestStartup>();
        }


        public HttpClient CreateClient()
        {
            return _webApplicationFactory.CreateClient();
        }
    }
}
```

A Test that executes against this test fixture

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task ResultsForQueryFound_RespondsOK()
    {
        var response = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync("/products/search",
                                                     new ProductSearchRequest
                                                     {
                                                         Query = "foo"
                                                     })
                                    .ToHelper();

        response.Should().HaveStatus(OK);
    }
```

I can generate code coverage for my Unit tests using [AltCover](https://github.com/SteveGilham/altcover) and this works great! But when i run altcover over my integration test project, I get no coverage results.

Has anyone been able to generate coverage for this type of test?